# what does "\E" escape in ANSI-C Quoting of bash shell?

Tags: bash, escaping, quoting, ansi-escape, ansi-c

i have read this article.[3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

i understand most of the content, but i have questions about this small part.

```
\e
\E
    an escape character (not ANSI C)
```

So what does it escape?
i tried to run

```
echo $'a\ebcdef'
```

It said:

```
acdef
```

It seems "\e" removes the following character. But when i try to run

```
echo $'a\e bcdef'
```

I got

```
a bcdef
```

**So what does the "\e" escape?**

Answer (score 1):

This is related to escape sequences to format the display (colors, blinking...): Cf. https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

For example, if you want to display "Hello world" in red:

```
$ echo $'\e[31mHello world\e[0m'
```

The same in green:

```
echo $'\e[32mHello world\e[0m'
```